# Shortcut в eclipse для частых выражений

Tags: eclipse

можно ли в eclipse создать shortcut'ы  для наиболее частых выражений тип out.print, (int i = 0...) и т.п.?

Answer (score 3):

Да. См. Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates